# How can I save objects and variables data in SAP gateway app?

Tags: abap

I've created back-end service in SAP gateway, I've written create and get entity's methods. But now how can I save internal objects and attributes between this methods calls? After calling back-end's create methods it needs to send internal table to front-end using get method. But all variables, objects and tables created in create method is empty when I'm calling get method.

Comment: SAP Gateway let you create stateless web services. Being stateless, do not expect to have some kind of persistence between two different calls. In order to help more please add more information (and code) to your question.

Answer (score 0):

REST and OData are stateless, meaning the server does not, and should not, share main memory between calls.

The typical way to solve this is to let CREATE store an object in the database, and GET retrieve it from there.

For large, segemented objects, `deep create` and `expand` reduce the number of client-server interactions.